# How to translate "something separates me from other people" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, usage

I'm trying to translate a song lyric that reads "something separates me from other people".

My translation is " 我从别人点儿什么分开“.

Is this correct? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Nice try, but not that correct.

Let’s disassemble this sentence.

The subject is: something / (1)什么东西

The verb is: separates / 分离，(2)将 ... 分离

The object is: me / (3)我

And the adverbial is: from other people / (4)从 其他人

So to re-assemble it in the Chinese way should be like:

(1)什么东西 (2)将 (3)我 (4)从 其他人 (2)分离

To clarify it: 什么东西将我从其他人分离。

Answer (score 1):

[Subject]: Something -  什么东西

[verb]: separates - 分开

[object]: me - 我

[adverbial]: from other people - 从其他人

- English grammar: [什么东西] [分开][我], [从其他人]
- Chinese grammar: [什么东西] [从其他人][分开][我]

(use deposit marker '将' to put object back before the adverbial)

> "有东西(将)我从其他人(那裡)分开" -- There is something separates me from other people

> "**有东西将我和其他人分开**" -- There is something separates me and other people

*more native to use [和 (~)] instead of [从 (~) 那裡]*

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to translate this sentence:

直译 (Literal translation): 某些事将我与他人分开

意译 ([Sense-for-sense translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense-for-sense_translation)): 我与他人不同之处在于

Comment: 我与他人不同之处在于 is "The thing that  separates me from other people is"

Answer (score 1):

It hurts to love you, but I still love you,
It's just the way I feel

Lana del Rey is really just complaining about the paparazzi in this song.

"13 Beaches"
十三片沙滩

I don't belong in the world
我与这个世界格格不入
That's what it is
就是这么回事
Something separates me from other people
我总与其他人有点不同
Everywhere I turn
我所到之处
There's something blocking my escape
总也无所遁形

Answer (score 1):

My attempt for this:  有些事物将我和别人分隔.

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answers here already, but I believe that the most succinct way to translate this hasn't been mentioned yet:

**与众不同**.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%88%87%E7%9C%BE%E4%B8%8D%E5%90%8C)

> different; distinct; standing out from the crowd

Answer (score 1):

**13个海滩**

I don't belong in the world
我不于这世

That's what it is
就是这样的

Something separates me from other people
某事与我分离他人

Everywhere I turn
到处我与转

There's something blocking my escape
某事挡我逃生